# Export List to Excel

Tags: c#

So I have a list of data that I am trying to export to excel. I just want to list it going down column 1 but it refuses. I was originally going to use a foreach loop but i was worried that would slow down my program and i wouldn't be able to use the for loop idea i had. Does anyone have any good ideas to just import this. I feel like it shouldn't be as hard as i am making it. This is what i have done so far. Thanks in advance.

```
if (dialog == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

    ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Folder Names";
    for (int row = 0; row <= count; row++)
    {
        ws.Cells [1, row+2] = Namelist;
    }
    excel.Visible = true;

}
```

I want to go sequentially down the list as well. (the code above wont export Namelist, rest works though)

Namelist = list
int count (it is a counter i started earlier in the program to determine the number of lines of Namelist)

Comment: What is the type of `Namelist` variable?

Comment: Is this an import to exisitng excel file or you just want to create a new file with the information in it?

Comment: all cells should be set to the same value (namelist) ?

Comment: It imports to a new excel doc. The goal is to go through the list and display  it in the same order but in excel with each item having its own cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop won't slow down your program, but accessing the cells individually will.  Each call to `Cells` is a COM-interop call, which is relatively expensive.  It's *much* faster to put your data in an array, define a `Range` that represents the entire range of output, and set the `Value` there:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var wbs = excel.Workbooks;
Workbook wb = wbs.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

List<object> data = new List<object>

data.Add("Folder Names");
for (int row = 0; row <= count; row++)
{
    data.Add(Namelist);
}

Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, 1], ws.Cells[1,count + 2]];
rng.Value = data.ToArray();
excel.Visible = true;
```

Comment: so if i wanted to adapt this for text in a separate textbox that is not in a list of any kind could i follow this for the most part?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but my point is don't set the values cell-by-cell - put the data in array and set the value of the _range_ to the array.

Comment: what library are you using excel doesn't come up as a keyword for me. Also, what I meant to say was that i had other information that i also wanted to put in the excel file. But i think i understand now what you meant by using the range

Comment: It is the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` class.  You can add `using Microsoft.Office.Interop` to the top of your cs file to include that namespace and avoid having to fully qualify the class.

Comment: I already included it. hmm I just wrote out the rest of it, but now it hates sheet keyword (sorry for all this trouble)

Comment: @Tasha That's my bad - I copied a different example and forgot to change the variable names.  See my edit.

Comment: @D Stanley, no problem. Could you explain why you chose to do rng.Value = data.toArray()? it claims there is an exception to determine the HRSEULT returned by the COM object

Comment: @Tasha Becasue `data` is a `List<object>` and `Value` requires an `object[]`.

Comment: @D Stanley, it throws an exception HRESULT returned by the COM object. I read a little about it that why I asked about it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What is the error?  Setting a range's value to an array of objects should not be a problem.

Comment: it says An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. And it is an exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC. It stops running the porggram right on rng.Value = data.ToArray()

Comment: Look at the inner exception to get more detail.  Also make sure the list and the range have the same number of rows.

Comment: So I was able to eliminate the error; however, data doesn't pick up any of the NameList values

Answer (score 2):

If Namelist is `List<string>`, the easiest way is to copy it to the Clipboard:

```
var text = "Folder Names\n" + string.Join("\n", Namelist);    // or "\r\n"
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(text);

var xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var wb = xl.Workbooks.Add();
var ws = xl.ActiveSheet as Worksheet;
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial();
xl.Visible = true;
```

or even easier because Excel is associated with .csv files by default:

```
var fileName = @"list.csv";    // or change to .xls and get warning message box
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, "Folder Names\n" + string.Join("\n", Namelist)); 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
```

**Update**

CSV stands for Comma Separated Values, so if you want the list in a different column you have to add commas before the values. For example in columns 2 and 4:

```
,Folder Names,,Folder Size
,name1,,256
,name2,,"1,024"
```

If you have 2 lists with the same size, you can zip them together:

```
string[] names = {"name1", "name2"}; 
int[] sizes = {256, 1024};

var lines = names.Zip(sizes, (name, size) => name + "," + size); // {"name1,256", "name2,1024"}
var csv = "Names,Sizes\n" + string.Join("\n", lines);
```

Comment: so lets say i want to paste it in a specific column, would you adjust the active cell

Comment: Sure, you can specify the address like `ws.Range("A1")` where A is the name of the column

Comment: So lets say that i use the .csv file version, how would you adjust the address then since you wouldn't be able to use worksheet

Comment: I don't understand var lines. Could you explain that portion more?

Comment: I guess I over-complicated it a bit. You can google "LINQ Zip" for more details

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Namelist` is a `string[]` or `List<string>` what you're missing is the extraction of each item from the `Namelist` collection before setting the value of each cell:

```
ws.Cells[1, 1] = @"Folder names";
for(int row = 2; row <= count; row ++)
{
    var name = Namelist[row-2];
    ws.Cells[1, row] = name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `Cells` property the first argument is the row, the second is the column. You have it reversed.

Also, if you haven't gone too far down the path of learning Excel interop, I would switch to [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). It's 100x times easier to work with, doesn't involve messing with COM objects, and doesn't even require Excel. It's just better.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy way to export your list to excel using c#

How to install ClosedXML with NuGet Packager Manager Console: 
 **PM> Get-Project *[ProjectName]* | Install-Package ClosedXML**

```
using (var conn = new DB.Entities())
{
    var stories = (from a in conn.Subscribers
                   orderby a.DT descending
                   select a).Take(100).ToList();

    var ShowHeader = true;
    PropertyInfo[] properties = stories.First().GetType().GetProperties();
    List<string> headerNames = properties.Select(prop => prop.Name).ToList();                
    var wb = new XLWorkbook();
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("Subscribers");
    if (ShowHeader)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < headerNames.Count; i++)                    
            ws.Cell(1, i + 1).Value = headerNames[i];

        ws.Cell(2, 1).InsertData(stories);
    }
    else
    {
        ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertData(stories);
    }

    wb.SaveAs(@"C:\Testing\yourExcel.xlsx");
}
```